# how to get all data from 4 relation table in laravel 5.5

Tags: orm, controller, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I am new on laravel and I was stuck at this problem, where I can't get all data from relation table,

This my **ERD** :
[image: this my ERD database]

This my **Krs.php** model :

```
protected $fillable = ['nim','nip','kode_mk','absen','uts','uas'];
protected $table = 'krs';

public function mahasiswa(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Mahasiswa');
}

public function dosen(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Dosen');
}

public function makul(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Matakuliah');
}
```

This my **Matakuliah.php** model :

```
protected $fillable = ['kode_mk','makul','sks'];
protected $table = 'mata_kuliah';

public function krs(){
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\Krs');
}
```

This my **Dosen.php** model :

```
protected $fillable =['nip','nama','jeniskelamin','alamat','notlp'];
protected $table='dosen';

public function krs(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Krs');
}
```

This my **Mahasiswa.php** model :

```
protected $fillable = ['nim','nama','alamat','jenis_kelamin','no_tlp','email','tempat','tanggal','link','id_jurusan'];
protected $table = 'mahasiswa';

public function jurusan(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Jurusan');
}

public function krs(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Krs');
}
```

and here is my **KrsController.php** :

```
 public function index()
{
   $data = Krs::with(['mahasiswa','dosen','makul'])->first()->toArray();
    return view('Krs.krsIndex',compact('data'));
}
```

how to get all data from all table? for example I want get **nama from mahasiswa** ? I don't know how to do it...I was try and searching from last night but still not change anything.. sorry for my bad grammar.thanks before

**Edit 1**
cannot get data from **mata_kuliah** table
this my blade syntax for print the data

```
{{ $data['makul'] }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **with()** function  :

```
$client_profile = Client::where([['cid', '=', $cid], ['is_delete', '=', 0]])->with(['status', 'group_no', 'caseworker', 'clerk', 'active_attendants'])->first()->toArray();
```

below is my model :

```
 class Client extends Model {
    public function status() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Status', 'sid', 'status');
    }

    public function group_no() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\ClientGroups', 'cgid', 'group_no');
    }

    public function caseworker() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Caseworker', 'cwid', 'caseworker_name');
    }

    public function clerk() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Supervisorsnurses', 'snid', 'clerk');
    }

    public function active_attendants() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\AssociatedTask', 'cid');
    }

    public function location() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Locations', 'lid', 'location');
    }
}
```

Comment: I try this  
`$data = Krs::with(['mahasiswa','dosen','makul'])->first()->toArray();
return view('Krs.krsIndex',compact('data'));`
but it does not work and the error say not found columns and the consumption RAM of PHP is going to high, do you have any solution?

Comment: Check my model once u have to send pk & foreign key in relation function

Comment: it's better and now the error say **Trying to get property of non-object **,,,,
I use `@foreach($data as $data) {{$data->name @endforeach}}` in index.blade.php is that right way to print data??

Comment: yes but first of all print $data then next... I think you have to access $data['name'] instead of $data->name

Comment: i can use $data['nim'] , but i can't get any column from another table,
this works $data['nip'];
this doesn't work $data['makul'];

Comment: update your question.. how you are trying let me know